# On Plotly Python, my widgets don't work : the graphs don't remove when I uncheck the box

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python, ipywidgets

I tried to use widgets by simply displaying a graph depending on checkboxes.

It shows the number of births along the years, for 2 cities (Grenoble and Vizille).

I want to display the evolution lines for 0, 1 or 2 cities depending on checkboxes.

At the beginning it's ok : it displays 0 lines, and then 1 or 2 when we check the boxes.

But if I uncheck a box, it doesn't remove a line.

What have I forgotten in my code ?

Here is a reproducible example :

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from ipywidgets import widgets

# CSV from URL
url = "https://entrepot.metropolegrenoble.fr/opendata/200040715-MET/insee/etat_civil_200040715.csv"
data_pop = pd.read_csv(url)

# Data prep
noms_col = data_pop.columns
data_pop.reset_index(inplace=True)
data_pop.drop(["code_postal"],axis=1,inplace=True)
data_pop.columns = noms_col

# Using widgets
use_Gre = widgets.Checkbox(
    description='Grenoble',
    value=False,
)

use_Viz = widgets.Checkbox(
    description='Vizille',
    value=False,
)

container_1 = widgets.HBox(children=[use_Gre, use_Viz])


g = go.FigureWidget(data=[{'type': 'scatter'}])

def validate1():
    if use_Gre.value is True:
        return True
    else:
        return False
    
def validate2():
    if use_Viz.value is True:
        return True
    else:
        return False 
    
    
def response1(change):
    if validate1():
        if use_Gre.value:
            trace01 = data_pop[data_pop['commune']=="Grenoble"].nombre_naissances
            x1=data_pop[data_pop['commune']=="Grenoble"].annee
        with g.batch_update():
            g.add_scatter(y=trace01,name="Grenoble", x= x1)
            
def response2(change):
    if validate2():
        if use_Viz.value:
            trace02 = data_pop[data_pop['commune']=="Vizille"].nombre_naissances
            x2=data_pop[data_pop['commune']=="Vizille"].annee
        with g.batch_update():
            g.add_scatter(y=trace02,name="Vizille", x= x2)
            
            
use_Gre.observe(response1, names="value")
use_Viz.observe(response2, names="value")

widgets.VBox([container_1, g])
```

Answer (score 2):

May I suggest using plotly.express? It would reduce your code significantly and already has a feature to show/hide plots from the legend:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

# CSV from URL
url = "https://entrepot.metropolegrenoble.fr/opendata/200040715-MET/insee/etat_civil_200040715.csv"
data_pop = pd.read_csv(url)

# Data prep
noms_col = data_pop.columns
data_pop.reset_index(inplace=True)
data_pop.drop(["code_postal"],axis=1,inplace=True)
data_pop.columns = noms_col

# keeping only the two cities of interest
data_pop = data_pop[data_pop['commune'].isin(['Grenoble', 'Vizille'])]

fig = px.line(x=data_pop['annee'], 
              y=data_pop['nombre_naissances'],
              color=data_pop['commune'])

# the option legendonly can be set to hide plot by default
for scat in fig.data:
    if scat.legendgroup == "Vizille":
        scat.visible = "legendonly"

fig.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Regarding your code, the problem is that your response functions replot the data each time you check the box but you don't delete it when the box is uncheck (you should do that in an else block)

Edit: corrected the code part regarding `legendonly`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of plotting an empty figure and adding traces to it, you could plot the traces in the first place and use the [`visible`](https://plotly.com/python/reference/scatter/#scatter-visible) property.

As suggested by @Tranbi, using the legend toggle does the trick and you don't necessarily need checkbox widgets.

Though, supposing you prefer to [hide the legend](https://plotly.com/python/reference/scatter/#scatter-showlegend) and use widgets only (ie. plan to add cities and/or more widgets), and to stick with plotly.graph_objects, you can refactor the code as follows :

```py
# Data prep
noms_col = data_pop.columns
data_pop.reset_index(inplace=True)
data_pop.drop(["code_postal"],axis=1,inplace=True)
data_pop.columns = noms_col

cities = ['Grenoble', 'Vizille']

# Named lists 
checkboxes = dict()
traces = dict()

for city in cities:
    # Widget
    checkboxes[city] = widgets.Checkbox(description=city, value=False)

    # Trace
    x = data_pop[data_pop['commune']==city].annee
    y = data_pop[data_pop['commune']==city].nombre_naissances
    traces[city] = go.Scatter(name=city, x=x, y=y, visible=False)

container_1 = widgets.HBox(children=list(checkboxes.values()))
fig = go.FigureWidget(data=list(traces.values()), layout=dict(showlegend=False))

def response(change):
    city = change.owner.description
    fig.update_traces(selector=dict(name=city), visible=checkboxes[city].value)

for checkbox in list(checkboxes.values()):
    checkbox.observe(response, names='value')

widgets.VBox([container_1, fig])
```

[image: notebook_gif]

Comment: Thank you very much ! With your code the lines don't appear but I can't find what is missing, do you see how to display the lines ?

Comment: Running this in your notebook should display the plot, just as your code (the only thing that is missing is the import statements and the first 2 lines for parsing data, which you need to run in previous cells). See the added gif anim.

Comment: Hum, strange, for me it didn't work with the same code and executing also the import statements and lines for parsing data, but if I open a new notebook it's ok. Thank you !